# python3: Unescape unicode escapes surrounded by unescaped characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, escaping, unicode-escapes

I received `json` data that has some unicode characters escaped, and others not.

```
>>> example = r'сло\u0301во'
```

What is the best way to unescape those characters? In the example below, what would the function `unescape` look like? Is there a built-in function that does this?

```
>>> unescape(example)
сло́во
```

Comment: That's odd, if you type `r'сло\u0301во'`, then the python interpreter will turn that escape into the corresponding character and the string will actually contain `сло́во`. It may *print that to the console* differently, depending on your code page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes that every instance of `\u` in the original string is a unicode escape:

```
def unescape(in_str):
    """Unicode-unescape string with only some characters escaped."""
    in_str = in_str.encode('unicode-escape')   # bytes with all chars escaped (the original escapes have the backslash escaped)
    in_str = in_str.replace(b'\\\\u', b'\\u')  # unescape the \
    in_str = in_str.decode('unicode-escape')   # unescape unicode
    return in_str
```

...or in one line...

```
def unescape(in_str):
    """Unicode-unescape string with only some characters escaped."""
    return in_str.encode('unicode-escape').replace(b'\\\\u', b'\\u').decode('unicode-escape')
```